# Как через js/jquery получить значение value из элемента <th>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

мне нужно получить значение value элемента, в данном случае 123

```
<th scope="row" id="product_id" value="123">something</th>
```

с помощью js/jquery

вот так не работает:

```
 var product_id = $("#product_id").val()
 alert(product_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

В целом тег `th` - предназначен для создания одной ячейки таблицы, которая обозначается как заголовочная и у него нет стандартного атрибута `value`. Потому и ваш код не работает. В данном случае вместо `value` лучше использовать `data`. Вот код который возвращает значения атрибута при нажатии на определенную ячейку таблицы.

```js
$('th').click(function(){
  var th_id = $(this).attr('value');
  
  alert(th_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="product_id1" value="some value 1">something 1</th>
    <th id="product_id2" value="some value 2">something 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="product_id3" value="some value 3">something 3</th>
    <th id="product_id4" value="some value 4">something 4</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Получаем значение атрибута value на чистом JavaScript:

```
alert(document.getElementById("product_id").getAttribute("value"));
```

html-разметка:

```
<table>
   <th scope="row" id="product_id" value="123">something</th>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как атрибут value для тега th не используется обработчиками его можно считать "кастомным". Соответственно, чтобы получить значение:

```js
var product_id = $('#product_id1').prop('value');
alert(product_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="product_id1" value="some value 1">something 1</th>
    <th id="product_id2" value="some value 2">something 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="product_id3" value="some value 3">something 3</th>
    <th id="product_id4" value="some value 4">something 4</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: а еще лучше `$('#product_id1').prop('value')`

Comment: @ryzen  теперь уже знаю, что да, так лучше